# How to center display resolution rather than stretching it?

Tags: drivers, display-resolution, configuration, external-monitor

I have a 2560*1440 monitor, and want to play a game at 1920*1080 or lower, with the image being centered on the monitor (at native 1:1 pixel). However, it is always stretched to full screen and things get ugly on wrong resolution. On Windows, it is very easy to change that setting in Radeon or Nvidia driver control panel. I cannot find the same place to do that on Ubuntu Cuttlefish.

[image: Nvidia Control Panel]
What I need is something equivalent to **No scaling** option. Image for illustration purpose. I am using Radeon card with Mesa driver, however.

Comment: Maybe with Xrandr, but not sure. Never heard of such option. I always use the native resolution anywhere.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia For most situations it is fine with native resolution. But maybe you have not played any RTS or MOBA game on a 27" monitor. It is too large to manage, and will increase your reaction time. That's why a smaller, centered screen is better.

Comment: ATM I only play Civilization 6 in a 32" 1080P TV :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing to a lower screen resolution without stretching](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264573/changing-to-a-lower-screen-resolution-without-stretching)