# Is it possible to use an ultrawide monitor (with the Nvidia driver) in widescreen resolution using part of the screen unused?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I would like to be able to use my ultrawide monitor as a normal widescreen monitor from time to time; instead of my desktop being at the native resolution of 3440x1440, I'd like a desktop of 2560x1440, using the central 2560 columns of the monitor and ignoring the rest:

[image: Desired setup]

I am using the NVidia video driver, and the i3 window manager.

I have tried to accomplish this with xrandr. I found promising posts such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1174798/xrandr-how-to-shift-output-that-is-lower-resolution-than-the-display-native-res) which would appear to be recipes for doing so. But if I try:

```
xrandr --fb 2560x1440 --output DP-0 --panning 2560x1440 --mode 2560x1440
```

then the monitor appears to be in 2560x1440 mode, with the desktop stretched across the whole monitor.

If I try to add a mode as suggested:

```
$ cvt 2560 1440 60                                                                                                                                                                                  
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode WEIRD2 312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --addmode DP-0 WEIRD
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

I believe this (inability to add a mode and assign it to the display - BadMatch) is an issue regarding the NVidia driver, and I couldn't see a workaround.

I got closer using the `nvidia-settings` application. It has an underscan mode. I used the following settings:

[image: Nvidia-settings]

This is very close; I see a 2560x1440 area in the middle of the monitor, and there's no panning evident, but the X session still seems to be seeing a wider desktop, which is truncated on the right.

[image: Result of nvidia-settings]

Can I do something with Xrandr to fix this desktop size? If I try `xrandr --fb 2560x1440`, I get `xrandr: specified screen 2560x1440 not large enough for output DP-0 (3440x1440+0+0)`.

Finally, as a workaround I can use i3-gaps and set the horizontal gaps to be 440 pixels. However, full screen mode for any window uses the whole monitor which is still not ideal.

Here's the [output](https://pastebin.com/1wnndD2U) from `xrandr`.

Here's the [output](https://pastebin.com/baKeqKmX) from `xrandr -v`.

And the [output](https://pastebin.com/b64L4uAi) from `nvidia-settings -q all`.

Is what I am trying to do possible, including being able to swap back and forth at will?

**Edited to add**:

[Output](https://pastebin.com/zNcucShs) from `hwinfo --monitor --gfxcard`

[Output](https://pastebin.com/U2v5pJx6) from `sudo lshw -C display`

Output from `cvt 2560 1440`:

`# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync`

Output from `gtf 2560 1440 60`:

`# 2560x1440 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 89.40 kHz; pclk: 311.83 MHz Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  311.83  2560 2744 3024 3488  1440 1441 1444 1490  -HSync +Vsync`

Comment: A note since this question still gets a lot of attention. I ultimately handled this in i3 with i3-gaps, so I just have a hot key to make the effective width narrower than the monitor as depicted. It's instant, and configurable per workspace.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the `BadMatch` error you may try adding/changing
in file `xorg.conf`, under `Section "Monitor"`, `HorizSync 30-90`, `VertRefresh 55-76`, or perhaps alternative setting (what is your current setting?), and reboot ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/380817/226614)).

You may also try removing the last argument to `cvt`, and let it choose it for you. Please post the output.

You may try also options `xrandr ... --set ...`, [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1276401/226614), [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/640132/226614) and `--scale`, [source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1316838/226614).

For some, `nvidia-settings` [worked](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=255287), YMMV.

You may also [try with the `nouveau` driver](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2324211).
Perhaps not a definitive answer, but it may help.

In the meantime, please post the output of

```
$ hwinfo --monitor --gfxcard
$ sudo lshw -C display
$ cvt 2560 1440
$ gtf 2560 1440 60
```

**Related**:

1. [Changing to a lower screen resolution without stretching](https://askubuntu.com/questions/264573/changing-to-a-lower-screen-resolution-without-stretching/1316838#1316838)
2. [How do you change the preferred resolution with xrandr?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1110387/how-do-you-change-the-preferred-resolution-with-xrandr)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed suggestions. I appended the additional info to the question. The use of `--set 'underscan'` also did not work, xrandr responds with `X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)`. Nouveau isn't an option. I'll test the xorg.conf/reboot suggestion later.

Comment: @Coljac - What about the suggestion of editing `xorg.conf`? What are your current settings? Please post *in the question*.